# Save Product with value from database // ProductName + DB-Value

Tags: product, custom, name, input

I am a Beginner. It was a challenge to code the module. But here I just can not get on. I hope someone can help me please.

The output of my module is working on view.phtml:

```
 <?php $custominput =  Mage::getStoreConfig('my_section/mygroup/my_field')?>

 <div class="product-name">
       <h1><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getName(), 'name') ?></h1>
       <h1><?php echo $custominput ;?></h1>              
 </div>
```

I need the $custominput inside the function/model/controller where the productname is added in backend. When saving the product name, the word from the database should be added directly.

```
'Productname' + 'custominput' -> SAVE = Productname custominput

'Productname custominput' + 'custominput' -> SAVE = Productname custominput custominput
```

Thanks -> god bless you ;)